# More than one condition in Mysql Between Condition Checking? Is there any way to optimize this query?

Tags: php, mysql, subquery, query-optimization, between

I am Working on report Generating Application, I am generating the query using **PHP** based on user operations. Now I am query the details based on the experience of the staff members, there is the possibilities for more than one selecting option. The Result is taken from joining 5 tables and sub queries, My Query is Working fine and fetching the exact result

First Scenario :
Taking Staff Members between total 15 to 20 Years Experience

Query

```
SELECT sd.staff_ref_id AS staff_code,
       sd.sur,
       sd.staff_name AS Name,
       sq.degree AS Qualification,
       sd.designation,
       d.department_name,
       TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, s.join_date, CURDATE()) AS rec_exp_months,
       sum(spe.years) AS p_exp_yrs,
       sum(spe.months) AS p_exp_months
FROM staff_details sd
LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT s.staff_id,
          group_concat(sq.degree) AS degree
   FROM staff_details s,
        staff_qualification sq
   WHERE s.staff_id = sq.staff_id
   GROUP BY sq.staff_id
   ORDER BY sq.row_num)sq ON sd.staff_id = sq.staff_id
LEFT JOIN staff_department s ON s.staff_id = sd.staff_id
LEFT JOIN department d ON d.department_id =s.depart_id
LEFT JOIN staff_previous_experience spe ON spe.staff_id = sd.staff_id
WHERE ((TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH,sd.join_date,CURDATE())) +
           (SELECT (sum(sqn.years)*12) + sum(sqn.months)
            FROM staff_previous_experience sqn
            WHERE sqn.staff_id=sd.staff_id
            GROUP BY sqn.staff_id) BETWEEN 120 AND 180)
GROUP BY staff_ref_id,
         sd.sur,
         sd.staff_name,
         sd.designation,
         d.department_name,
         sq.degree,
         s.join_date
```

Second Scenario: Taking staff members between total experience 10 to 15 years and 15 to 20 years Experience

Query

```
SELECT sd.staff_ref_id AS staff_code,
       sd.sur,
       sd.staff_name AS Name,
       sq.degree AS Qualification,
       sd.designation,
       d.department_name,
       TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, s.join_date, CURDATE()) AS rec_exp_months,
       sum(spe.years) AS p_exp_yrs,
       sum(spe.months) AS p_exp_months
FROM staff_details sd
LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT s.staff_id,
          group_concat(sq.degree) AS degree
   FROM staff_details s,
        staff_qualification sq
   WHERE s.staff_id = sq.staff_id
   GROUP BY sq.staff_id
   ORDER BY sq.row_num)sq ON sd.staff_id = sq.staff_id
LEFT JOIN staff_department s ON s.staff_id = sd.staff_id
LEFT JOIN department d ON d.department_id =s.depart_id
LEFT JOIN staff_previous_experience spe ON spe.staff_id = sd.staff_id
WHERE ((TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH,sd.join_date,CURDATE())) +
           (SELECT (sum(sqn.years)*12) + sum(sqn.months)
            FROM staff_previous_experience sqn
            WHERE sqn.staff_id=sd.staff_id
            GROUP BY sqn.staff_id) BETWEEN 120 AND 180
         OR (TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH,sd.join_date,CURDATE())) +
           (SELECT (sum(sqn.years)*12) + sum(sqn.months)
            FROM staff_previous_experience sqn
            WHERE sqn.staff_id=sd.staff_id
            GROUP BY sqn.staff_id) BETWEEN 180 AND 240)
GROUP BY staff_ref_id,
         sd.sur,
         sd.staff_name,
         sd.designation,
         d.department_name,
         sq.degree,
         s.join_date
```

Note: The above highlighted area, i am checking total experience, i am converting both input and result from database as months and checking the conditions

Question : The Darken Area is generated query from php, that i am using the **between query**..based on how much options selected from experience field, the **between query** will be automatically generated..

**Is There any way to Optimize this..?**

**Is there an option to use between option in query for several conditions ...?**

My Query Execution Time is 0.0663 sec

awaiting Responses, Suggestions and advice's
*Thanks in Advance*

Comment: Okay i will try my max

Comment: @Md Mahfuzur Rahman.. Thank you so much

Comment: sadly, the  highlight now is only some ** in the code ;o/

Comment: @Jakumi, Now how can i high light that

Comment: I proposed an edit. (`<pre><code>...<b>...</b>...</code></pre>` instead of indenting with 4 spaces.

Comment: The `GROUP BY` in the highlighted subquery is unnecessary.

Comment: The `ORDER BY row_num` is probably invalid and ignored because of the `GROUP BY`.

Comment: It seems like `s` is unnecessary in the derived table after the `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: Why separately compute BETWEEN 120 AND 180 and BETWEEN 180 AND 240?  Seems like they could be merged together.

Comment: @RickJames, I Accepted your suggestions, i removed group by and order by in sub query

Comment: @RickJames In Above, I can able to merge 120 and 180 and BETWEEN 180 and 240. Similarly users select 60 and 120 and Between 180 and 240, such case i cant able to merge. That's why i separated that

Comment: @Jakumi Thank you for alignment, Now i learned to align

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It feels like this will give you the same effect as the first `WHERE`:

```
WHERE sd.join_date >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 180 MONTH
  AND sd.join_date  < CURDATE() - INTERVAL 120 MONTH
```

And have `INDEX(join_date)`.

If so, then it is so much simpler that is must be faster.

The `GROUP BY` in the highlighted subquery is unnecessary.

The `ORDER BY row_num` is probably invalid and ignored because of the `GROUP BY`.

It seems like s is unnecessary in the derived table after the `LEFT JOIN`.

Why separately compute `BETWEEN 120 AND 180` and `BETWEEN 180 AND 240`? Seems like they could be merged together.

If it is not faster, then make the cleanups I suggested in comments and let's start over.  And please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each table.

Comment: I accepted your suggestions..Thank you so much for your response, This is also a same response time as which i compared to before.. I will start again from beginings